# Extract time slot based on interval value

Tags: excel, vba, unique, excel-2007, array-formulas

In cell A1 I have an interval value which is an integer which can either be 1, 5 or 15 which means 1 minute, 5 minutes or 15 minutes

In range "B1:B12", I have the sample data (it will be more)

```
12:03
12:03
12:06
12:06
12:09
12:11
12:14
12:15
12:15
12:16
12:31
12:32
```

Now in column C, I need to extract time slots based on number is available in cell A1.

If cell A1 has 15 then the column C would contain below

```
12:15
12:30
```

because first 15th minute in column starts at 12:15 then increment it by 15 mins until last available data which falls in that 15 min range.

If cell A1 has 5 then the column C would contain below

```
12:05
12:10
12:15
12:30
```

because first 5th minute starts at 12:05 then increment it by 5 mins until last available data which falls in that 15 min range.

and if cell A1 has 1 then extract **everything except duplicates**.

I hope I have explained the scenario properly. I am not able to think of a logic to do this in excel vba and need help with how to start so that I can try to apply the logic and comeup with a code.

Thank you

## EDIT

I am adding a pic of the desired result.
if A1 contains 1 then copy all timestamps in column C without the duplicates

if A1 contains 5 then show only 5 times of 5 min interval

if A1 contains 15 then show only 3 times of 15 min interval

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? I think this is a rather simple formula.

Comment: I am afraid that the question is not so clear as you think... You are talking about "1, 5 or 15". The A1 values like '12:03', `12:06' and similar, not included in the firstly mentioned range will they be neglected? Then, should the code iterate between all values in B:B and how to return in C:C? Exactly how you show us? I mean the values one on top of the other? What format does the B:B range have? What format to be in C:C? What does "cell A1 has 1 then extract everything except duplicates" mean? What this extraction does mean? Do you want referring to B?

Comment: I would suggest you to edit your question and place two pictures. One with the existing situation and the second showing how it must be after processing...

Comment: @FaneDuru no they should not be neglected and yes code to be iterate between all values in B and return in C. The range does not have any formula and format in C would be time format. In short, I am looking to group all the timestamp in groups of 1 min, 5 min and 15 min. I will edit my question with pic of desired output

Comment: Now I am looking to your picture and can conclude that NOBODY in this world could not understand your question as it was expressed before editing. It was such a simple task, but not clearly described...

Comment: i am so sorry for the inconvenience. i may have not explained it well. thank you so much for looking into it. god bless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VBA (1) returning an array

You will need to `ctrl-shif-enter`

```
Option Explicit

Function get_unique_time_interval(ByVal interval_size As Double, ByVal input_data As Range) As Variant

  interval_size = interval_size / 60# / 24#
  
  Dim d
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  
  Dim r As Range
  For Each r In input_data
    Dim t As Double
    t = Int(r.Value / interval_size) * interval_size
    If Not d.exists(t) Then d.Add t, t
  Next r
  
  get_unique_time_interval = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(d.keys)

End Function
```

(2) hard-coded outputting to `C1`

```
option explicit
Sub get_unique_time_interval_sub()

  Dim interval_size As Double: interval_size = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Value
  Dim input_data As Range: Set input_data = Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("b1"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("b1").End(xlDown))
  
  interval_size = interval_size / 60# / 24#
  
  Dim d
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  
  Dim r As Range
  For Each r In input_data
    Dim t As Double
    t = Int(r.Value / interval_size) * interval_size
    If Not d.exists(t) Then d.Add t, t
  Next r
  
  Dim v As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  i = 0
  If Not IsEmpty(Range("c1").Value) Then Range(Range("c1"), Range("c1").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
  For Each v In d.keys
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("c1").Offset(i, 0).Value = v
    i = i + 1
  Next v

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

this works as a single cell formula in `C1`:

```
=UNIQUE(INT(B1:B12/(A1/60/24))*(A1/60/24))
```

[image]

breaking it down:

```
A1/60/24
```

is the time interval you want (`A1` in minutes so divide by 60 mins per hour and 24 hours per day to get to Excel time interval units). Then:

```
INT(B1:B12/(A1/60/24))
```

rounds you down to the start of the time period. Then:

```
*(A1/60/24)
```

converts you back up to the time of the interval in which the input time falls. Then:

```
UNIQUE(
```

pulls out the unique values.

The helpful thing here is that by including `B1:B12` as a range it makes everything (helpfully) spill

Comment: Thanks for your reply... i tried to put the formula in C1 but it shows #NAME? for me

Comment: guess that could be a typo - can u screenshot the cell contents? What version of excel are u using and what language?

Comment: i am using excel 2007. i added screenshot under your answer

Comment: Ah ok - feature is not available in 2007 - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_o365b/unique-function-not-available/d26e06fe-a5f3-4a6a-bec4-a32469ad8339 - is there any reason why you do not want to do this as a VBA macro?

Comment: i am ok with a macro or formula based solution... anything that gives me the result. Thanks for your help the formula looks great... I really wish to check this out on a different computer with latest excel. I will check it out tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

If you accept a formula based answer then This should work for you:

A1: some inteval value.

B1:

```
=0.5+A1/(24*60)
```

Where 0.5 mean 12:00 in Excel.

In B2:

```
=B1+$A$1/(24*60)
```

And drag this formula down to where you need it.

Exampls:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks... seems like a good logic using formulas but it does not give my desired result. Let me post a pic of how the desired output would look like.

Comment: i posted the pic. appreciate if you could look at it and let me know if there is a way to achieve this in a formula based solution. data in coulmn B is raw data. I dont need formulas there... i need the output in column C